Finding the basis for the Lie Algebra of Killing vector fields with respect to the Euclidean metric
Let $K$ denote the Lie Algebra of Killing vector fields with respect to the Euclidean metric, and let $K_0\subset K$ denote the subspace consisting of fields that vanish at the origin. Show that the following vector fields form a basis for $K$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \; 1\le i\le n; \; x^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} - x^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \; 1\le i<j\le n.$$
I have shown that the map $$V \mapsto (\frac{\partial{V^i}}{\partial x^j}(0))$$ is an injective linear map from $K_0$ to the Lie Algebra of real skew symmetric matrices.
I also know that $V$ is a Killing Vector field if and only if
$$\frac{\partial V^j}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^j}=0.$$
I think the first $n$ vectors form the basis for $K-K_0$ and the remaining vectors form the basis for $K_0$ but I cannot figure out why.
How can I use this result to show that the above form a basis for $K$? I would greatly appreciate some help.
